# Get facebook username using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, windows-phone-8

Hi is there any way where i can get user's facebook username using their email and password? I have already done the authentication for user to login with facebook but i need a way to get the username and store it inside my windows azure datatable. Im doing this in a windows phone 8 app using c#. Thanks

Comment: **You should never have a user's Facebook password.** _Use OAuth_.

Comment: yes i have used OAuth authentication, but how do i get the username and store only the username in my azure datatable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the Open Graph API. You can see a list of obtainable fields for a user [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), user name being one of them.

If you're not already using a Facebook SDK of some sort Facebook SDK for .NET is great. Check out a great step by step tutorial using the following link. http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial The section titled "Personalize" will show you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should play around with this official graph API sandbox

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

More precisely, you have the access token, then you do

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

or only return id and username

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=username&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

That's all.